# Single Sign On in Google+ without using Account Manager

Tags: android, authentication, webview, gmail, google-oauth

I am trying to **Login with Google+** in one of my application. I am using `WebView` to login user and after fetching `auth` token I would like to get some user information like name, email-address etc.

I know the scenario of **[AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html#choose)**.

But instead of using account which are already stored, I want user to login using `WebView`, and after successfully login, I want his email-id as information.

I am trying following short of code. But I am getting **401** exception. `java.io.IOException: Unauthorized`

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://mail.google.com");
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        Log.d("Home", "Url :" + url);
        String requestToken = "";
        if (url.contains("auth=")) {
            requestToken += url.substring(url.indexOf("auth=") + 5);
            Log.d("Home", "Request Token : " + requestToken);
            requestUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token="
                    + requestToken;
            view.stopLoading();
            new CustomThread().start();
        }

    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // Log.d("Home", "Url :" + url);
        // Log.d("Home", view.getUrl());
    }
});

public class CustomThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(requestUrl));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                Log.d("Home", "Response : " + out.toString());

                CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
                // Get the cookie from cookie jar.
                String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(
                        requestUrl);
                if (cookie == null) {
                    Log.d("Home", "Cookie is Null");
                    return;
                }
                // Cookie is a string like NAME=VALUE [; NAME=VALUE]
                String[] pairs = cookie.split(";");
                for (int i = 0; i < pairs.length; ++i) {
                    String[] parts = pairs[i].split("=", 2);
                    // If token is found, return it to the calling activity.
                    if (parts.length == 2
                            && parts[0].equalsIgnoreCase("oauth_token")) {
                        Log.d("Home", "Token :" + parts[1]);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("Home", "Error : " + statusLine.getStatusCode());
                // Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **[Social-Auth for Android](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/)** to do so with following code.

```
SocialAuthAdapter adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());

imgGoogle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        adapter.authorize(YourActivity.this, Provider.GOOGLE);
    }
});

private final class ResponseListener implements DialogListener {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        //successful authentication..
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(SocialAuthError error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBack() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using WebView, for Google+ Sign-In it’s a lot easier to use the PlusClient, then everything works with a native experience. See https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in